# How to checkout a new local branch using go-git?

Tags: go, go-git

When i try to use worktree checkout; it doesn't work and the code returns error

```
err = worktree.Checkout(&git.CheckoutOptions{
    Create: true,
    Branch: "main",
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Cannot create 'main' branch\n" + err.Error())
}
```

Output:

```
[FATA] Cannot create 'main' branch
reference not found
```

I get the same error when i use

```
repository.CreateBranch(&config.Branch{
    Name: "main",
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is true [GitHub will soon rename `master` to `main`](https://github.com/github/renaming), the default branch for a Git repository (on GitHub or not) is still `master` for now.

So try first:

```golang
err = worktree.Checkout(&git.CheckoutOptions{
    Create: true,
    Branch: "master",
})
```

But if the goal is to create a new branch, make sure the repo is either initialized or already checked out to a valid branch.
For example, see [`repository_test.go`](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/63d92533b538cb380667deee5dc6d32f0946c737/repository_test.go#L286-L292)

```golang
    r, _ := Init(memory.NewStorage(), nil)
    testBranch := &config.Branch{
        Name:   "foo",
        Remote: "origin",
        Merge:  "refs/heads/foo",
    }
    err := r.CreateBranch(testBranch)
```

---

The [OP capsci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10442853/capsci) adds in the comments:

> I tried removing Merge during branch create, but got "`reference not found`" error when checking out (w/ and w/o Create option)
>
> I ended up using hack in [`hairyhenderson/gomplate` PR 1217](https://github.com/hairyhenderson/gomplate/pull/1217):
>
> ```
> h := plumbing.NewSymbolicReference(plumbing.HEAD, plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/heads/main")) 
> err = storer.SetReference(h);
> ```
>
> these 2 lines after `git.Init(storer, fs)`, and I was good to go.

Comment: Thanks @VonC, but above did not help. The new commits i make still go on 'master' branch

Comment: @capsci Your original question (18 months ago) was talking about an error, not about commits going to master. Anyway, once you have created the branch (using the code in my answer), you still need to checkout it first, *then* create commits: they will go on the new branch (because of the checkout)

Comment: Hi @VonC, sorry for updating this after 18 months

Comment: Hi @VonC, I should I've explained the problem better. Basically, I was trying to checkout a new "main" branch on an empty repo.

`repo, err := git.Init(memory.NewStorage(), memfs.New())`  
`err = repo.CreateBranch(&config.Branch{Name:”main”,Merge:  "refs/heads/foo"})`
`worktree,err := repo.Worktree()`
`err = worktree.Checkout(&git.CheckoutOptions{Branch: “main”})`

I still get "reference not found" error when I Checkout newly created branch (with or without 'Create' set in CheckoutOptions). Can you please let me know what else am I missing?

Comment: @capsci For testing, I would avoid the Merge "refs/heads/foo" part: when you just initialized a repository, I am sure that particular reference ("foo" branch) would not be found.

Comment: Hi @VonC, thanks for comment. I tried removing Merge during branch create, but got "reference not found" error when checking out (w/ and w/o Create option)

I ended up using hack in https://github.com/hairyhenderson/gomplate/pull/1217
`h := plumbing.NewSymbolicReference(plumbing.HEAD, plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/heads/main"))`
`err = storer.SetReference(h)`; these 2 lines after `git.Init(storer, fs)` and I was good to go

Thanks again for your help and pointers :)

Comment: FYI, I also tried committing to default branch(master) and then creating and checking-out "main".
But this resulted both "master" and "main" branches when I performed `remote.Push()`.

In a follow up attempt; I wondered if I can delete "master" branch from my local in-memory "git init" before performing Push; but `*Repository.Branches` listed both "master" and "main"; but `*Repository.Config.Branches`(which is used by `*Repository.DeleteBranch`) did not have "master" for some reason. I might be connecting too many dots here. But just sharing what I saw.

Comment: @capsci Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment/option in the answer for more visibility.